# Animate sibling element's height based on element's animating height

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Sub Block Toggle's parent has variable height.
When on click Sub Block Toggle, the Lorem Ipsum block should reduce and expanding depending on the height left.

The Sub Block cannot have a background color so it's not a matter of simple overlapping the Lorem Ipsum with the background of Sub Block.

That leaves me with having the animate the height of the Lorem Impsum text, but because the Sub Block's height is variable, and onload set to hidden, I cannot use scrollHeight.

Anyone here can point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated.

```js
$('.footer-subblock-title').on('click', function(el) {
  console.log('clicked');
  $(this).next().animate({
    height: ["toggle", "swing"]
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  background: #bae0c4;
  position: relative;
  font: 14px/1.65em Arial;
}
.body .container {
  top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
}
.body .container .footer-block {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  bottom: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.body .container .footer-subblock {
  overflow: hidden;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="title">
      Title Goes Here
    </h3>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="footer-block">
      <h4 class="footer-subblock-title">
        Sub Block Toggle  
      </h4>
      <div class="footer-subblock" style="display:none;">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
        <br/>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
        <br/>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/32dk3txg/

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't get it. you want to show "subblock" without interfering with the other text? Or you want the other text to shrink in height so that it does not touch the "subblock"?

Comment: @zero point - it's basically both. The text height needs to shrink as the subblock height increases. But because the subblock doesn't have a background, i can't just be happy with the overlap taking care of the hiding of the text.

Comment: @zero point - the other text needs to shrink in height so it doesn't touch the subblock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with a little jQuery. Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/xZoNQM?editors=1010).Since your HTMl markup had some issue with unnecessary divs, I made it a little simpler, but the principle of the solution will work with your code as well:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var origMaxHeight = $(".sub-block").css("max-height");
  var newHeight = $(".sub-block").height();

  $(".sub-block").click(function() {

    if ($(this).css("max-height") == origMaxHeight) {
       $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
         maxHeight: "10em"
       }, {
         duration: 500,
         queue: false,
         progress: function() {
            $(".text").height($(".text").height() - $(this).height() + newHeight); 
            newHeight =  $(this).height(); 
         }
       });


     } else {
       $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
         maxHeight: "1em"
       }, {
         duration: 500,
         queue: false,
         progress: function() {
            $(".text").height($(".text").height() - $(this).height() + newHeight); 
            newHeight =  $(this).height(); 
         }
       });
     }
  })
});
```

The idea is to use `progress` callback on `animate` function to modify height of `text` element in each step. The if-statement on `$(this).css("max-height")` will make us able to distinguish between first click (which increases `.sub-block` height) from the second click (which somehow closes the `.sub-block` element). The rest is very straight-forward. Hope it is not too late :)